# Нужны ли здесь еще какие-то знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

А для определения по запросу наш кран или нет, мы обязательно запросим фото, паспорт и данные поставщика, который поставил кран на объект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов оформления: А для определения по запросу "наш кран или нет", мы обязательно запросим фото, паспорт и данные поставщика, который поставил кран на объект.

Это прямая речь в роли определения.